# Como saber se uma função foi chamada por outro formulário?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Como saber se uma função foi chamada por outro formulário?

**Por exemplo:**

No meu formulário 1, tenho um método que chama outro formulário:

```
private void btnFormulario2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   frmFormulario2 frm2 = new frmFormulario2();
   frm2.Show();    
}
```

No meu formulário 2, tenho a esse método que grava no banco:

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GravaNoBanco();    
}
```

Existe uma maneira do Formulario 1 saber se o Formulario 2 chamou a função que grava no banco?

Comment: Sim, você precisa criar um evento para isto e notificar os interessados. No caso o formulário um teria que assinar o evento para ser notificado. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, existe essa possibilidade, você pode fazer o seguinte, ao invés de `form.Show()` você pode usar um `form.ShowDialog()`

```
bool clicado = false;
private void btnFormulario2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   frmFormulario2 frm2 = new frmFormulario2();
   DialogResult result = frm2.ShowDialog();    
   if(result == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       clicado = true;
   }
}
```

e no seu form2

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GravaNoBanco(); 
   DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;   
}
```

Caso não queira fazer com `ShowDialog`, você terá de criar uma variável global estática no seu form1

```
public static bool clicado = false;
```

e no seu form2 ao clicar em salvar

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GravaNoBanco();
   Form1.clicado = true;
}
```

Existem maneiras melhores, mas isso já resolve.